# Handle multiple errors with one UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, uialertcontroller, urlsession

I have two classes which provide delegate methods that report various errors when fetching data from an API. The `HttpAPI` fetches weather data and the `RadarAPI` fetches a radar image. The code below is in the `HomeViewController` which handles the data or errors from each API.

```
// MARK: - HttpAPI Delegate

extension HomeViewController: HttpAPIDelegate {

    func apiSessionError(_ error: Error) {
        // show alert with error from url session
    }

    func apiHttpError(_ code: Int) {
        // show alert with HTTP error code
    }

    func apiJsonError(_ error: Error) {
        // show alert with json error
    }

    func apiSuccess(_ json: [String: Any]) {
        // update app with weather data
    }
}

// MARK: - RadarAPI Delegate

extension HomeViewController: RadarAPIDelegate {

    func radarSessionError(_ error: Error) {
        // show alert for url session error
    }

    func radarHttpError(_ code: Int) {
        // show alert with HTTP response error code
    }

    func radarImageError(_ error: String) {
        // show alert with image parsing error message
    }

    func radarSuccess(_ image: UIImage) {
        // update app with weather radar image
    }    
}
```

I would like to show an alert if an error occurs from fetching the weather data or when retrieving the radar image. The problem is that if an error occurs in the `HttpAPI` then the `RadarAPI` will also give an error; therefore, two `UIAlertControllers` will be presented which is not recommended.

How can I handle multiple error messages and present those errors in a single `UIAlertController`?

Answer (score 0):

Why 2 `UIAlertControllers` aren't allowed to be presented?

Anyway, if you don't want to show 2 different alerts, try doing a mechanism where you wait for both responses before decided what to show.

Comment: Only one alert controller can be presented at a time. It is also bad practice to show multiple alerts, it is better to show one alert. Regarding your answer, can you provide some example code of such a mechanism in Swift?

Comment: If you want to present more than 1 UIAlertController, create your own custom class, and make the UIAlertController have its own UIWindow which it presents itself from.

Comment: I do not want to create multiple alerts. I want one alert that will show multiple error messages from the `HttpAPI` and `RadarAPI`.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide code right now, but when submitting the requests, try creating a class with a shared instance and set 2 flags named for example `receivedRadarAPI` and `receivedHttpAPI`. Set both those to false, and when you receive the responses set them to true separately. When both flags are true, you can show the alert.